# Android AlarmManager with SQL

Tags: java, android

I have a project which use SQLite database to trigger an alarm in specific time from database I use android alarm manager in my project and use broadcast receiver to manage alarm at boot time here is a sample of AlarmCode:

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_ID, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    //lollipop_mr1 is 22, this is only 23 and above
    // alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, then.getMillis()-G.AzanDelayTime, alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, then.getMillis(), alarmIntent);


  } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    //JB_MR2 is 18, this is only 19 and above.
    //alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, then.getMillis()-G.AzanDelayTime, alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, then.getMillis(), alarmIntent);
  }
  else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

    alarmMgr.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(then.getMillis(), alarmIntent), alarmIntent);
    Toast.makeText(G.context,"This is sdk>21",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
  else {
    //available since api1
    //alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, then.getMillis()-G.AzanDelayTime, alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, then.getMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

but I want to my alarm fire off at the exact time in every device and in some case the alarm went off in margin of 15 minutes or less what is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlarmManagerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AlarmManagerCompat):

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...)
```

or

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setAlarmClock(...)
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using AlarmManagerCompat instead of AlarmManager ??

Comment: The class handles all the if/else branches you wrote in your code @SeyedMassoudMotallebi

Comment: OK, it sounds good but what happens to exact timing my request is the alarm went of at exact time on every devices..